# Add Libraries from Backed Up Managed Libraries Folder in CoDeSys

Tags: codesys

Recently I had a computer failure that resulted in reinstalling the windows operating system. Fortunately, I was able to back up my machine before doing the reinstall. However, I am now trying to make my CoDeSys project compile but I can't seem to figure out how to make CoDeSys recognize the libraries located in `C:\ProgramData\CODESYS\Managed Libraries\`. Before I reinstalled the operating system I was able to back up the managed libraries directory and now I have copied the directory back to the `C:\ProgramData\CODESYS\Managed Libraries\` location. I can see the `CODESYS library` files in the directory through the file explorer but CoDeSys does not recognize them.

I have attempted to add a repository location using the library repository but I when I add a dummy location it won't let me delete the original location (to then re-add it).

I am using CoDeSys 3.5 SP11 Patch 4. I understand this is not the newest version of CoDeSys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to copy libraries to this catalogue.
You need to install package with all hardware from your supplier.

What you have to do is download the .package file from supplier of your hardware.
Then you have to open codesys go to tools -> package manager -> install.

After that library will be installed properly.

Please take a look for this youtube movie if I didn't explain it well.
https://youtu.be/GFkA4E1R4aQ?t=393

Cheers!